# Bash Grep Quiet SSH Output

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to match the output of an SSH command but for some reason it's not working. I'm using authorized_keys to restrict the login to one command - which is a wrapper script that takes parameters.

Here's my code:

```
for i in `seq 2 254`; do
  myoutput=$( ssh system@server01 ip 192.168.0.$i )
  echo "$myoutput"
  echo "$myoutput" | grep -q "not found"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 192.168.0.$i
    exit
  fi
done
```

Here's the output of the script:

```
192.168.0.2 not found in DB.  Try searching live (--forcelive)
192.168.0.3 not found in DB.  Try searching live (--forcelive)
192.168.0.4 not found in DB.  Try searching live (--forcelive)
```

This should stop at the first instance and echo the IP but it's continuing along because ALL of the greps are returning 1 rather than 0. The SSH command itself (without the grep) returns 0 every time.

**Why is grep miscoding the response? Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm wanting to do?**

Comment: #1. You missed the `done` at the end of the code. #2, please indent the `for` loop. #3, don't use `return` as a variable name as it clearly conflicts with a shell builtin.

Comment: #4 Instead of `if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then` try to do `if echo "$return" | grep -q "not found"; then` or better yet `if grep -q <<< "$return"; then`

Comment: `if` checks the return value of a command. It's just that we get so used to seeing the `test` command (`[`) or the shell builtin `[[` that we forget that any return code will do.

Comment: Very likely this content is on stderr, not stdout.

Comment: BTW, do you know if the exit status of the `ip` command you're using varies based on whether it finds something? In general, checking a command's exit status is far better practice than trying to interpret its output.

Comment: BTW, running your script with `bash -x yourscript` will add logging which would do a great deal to clear up the questions here.

Comment: @user3063045, Were there extra newlines in the output that you truncated when you presented it here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content you're trying to search for is almost certainly on stderr, so your substitution isn't capturing it at all; thus, it's being emitted to the console by the same command that invokes ssh rather than placed in the `myoutput` variable.

Consider using the redirection `2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout, as so:

```
myoutput=$( ssh system@server01 "ip 192.168.0.$i" 2>&1 )
```

---

By the way, if you're okay with the overhead of calling `ssh` over two hundred times, I would seriously consider rewriting this like so:

```
for ((i=2; i<254; i++)); do
  if ssh system@server01 "ip 192.168.0.$i" 2>&1 | grep -q 'not found'; then
    echo "192.168.0.$i"
    exit
  fi
done
```

Why?

- `seq` is neither built into bash, nor POSIX-specified. Thus, it's not guaranteed even to exist, much less to behave in any particular way.
- The command line passed by ssh to a remote system is built as a single string generated by concatenating arguments. Passing only a single string with the exact code you wish to execute is thus a more honest representation of what goes on under the hood, and avoids bugs that can be created by forgetting what ssh *really* does with its command line.
- Using `$?` is bad form when you can simply test for success of a command directly.

---

If you weren't restricted by `authorized_keys`, by the way, you'd be much better off moving the script evaluation to the remote system, something like:

```
ip_found=$(ssh system@server01 bash -s <<'EOF'
  for ((i=2; i<254; i++)); do
    content=$(ip "192.168.0.$i" 2>&1)
    if [[ $content = *"not found"* ]]; then
      echo "192.168.0.$i"
      exit 0
    fi
  done
  exit 1
EOF
)

echo "Remote system found $ip_found"
```

...since you *are* so restricted, you might -- for performance reasons -- consider using [SSH multiplexing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing) to reuse a single authenticated connection over your many queries.

Comment: That can't be true if the output is coming from the line `echo "$myoutput"`

Comment: Sure, but my point is that the OP is almost certainly **wrong** in their supposition that the output is coming from the `echo`. Unless they've run their script with `set -x`, they don't know for sure.

Comment: Makes sense. `stderr` would still be printed even if `stdout` is not because of the `$(...)`. Wouldn't the `echo` add extra newlines between each entry though?

Comment: Ooh -- that's a question I don't have a good answer for, indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and advice!

Comment: Another note: some non-GNU `grep` implementations don't do `-q` correctly (see GNU `grep`'s man page), so the recommendation for portable code is to pipe its output to /dev/null.  Generally, you also get a speedup by using `-l` (list the file) since it'll stop at the first match (`-q` also has this benefit), but not in this case since you're parsing something so small.

Comment: Thank you, I could not find out that is going on anywhere else!